# Pause the duration of a Ticker

Tags: flutter, dart

Is there any way to pause a Ticker in Dart/Flutter?

I tried using

```
Ticker t = Ticker(print);
t.start();
t.muted = true;
```

This does pause the ticks, but the `Stopwatch` that could have been implicitly set still seems to continue working. Is there any way to stop it or maybe some efficient workaround if I rely on the duration to perform something like an animation?

Comment: Hi did you find an answer? The .stop will reset the duration. So IMHO I may just use .stop and maintain my own Duration

Comment: Hey, I know I'm too late...This is one of my temporary accounts so I don't check it frequently; I am checking this thread after a long time.. I needed this solution for my state management library and I had implemented a solution similar to the accepted answer. I'm no longer in touch with Flutter...but alas I miss those days :( Packed with some other work now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is my solution (not fully tested):

**EDIT 2**: Tested and already used in my project.

```
import 'package:flutter/scheduler.dart';

typedef void ResumableTickerCallback(Duration duration);

class ResumableTicker {
  final ResumableTickerCallback _callback;

  Ticker _ticker;
  Duration _offset = Duration.zero;
  Duration _lastTickRawDuration = Duration.zero;

  ResumableTicker.fromProvider(TickerProvider vsync, this._callback) {
    _ticker = vsync.createTicker(_tick);
  }

  void _tick(Duration rawDuration) {
    _lastTickRawDuration = rawDuration;
    _callback(_getActualFromTickRawDuration(rawDuration));
  }

  Duration _getActualFromTickRawDuration(Duration rawDuration) => rawDuration + _offset;

  Duration get lastTickDuration => _getActualFromTickRawDuration(_lastTickRawDuration);

  void startOrResume() {
    _ticker.start();
  }

  void pause() {
    _ticker.stop();
    _offset = lastTickDuration;
    _lastTickRawDuration = Duration.zero; // to keep last tick ACTUAL duration unchanged
  }

  void seek(Duration newTime) {
    final delta = newTime - _getActualFromTickRawDuration(_lastTickRawDuration);
    _offset += delta;
    _lastTickRawDuration = newTime - _offset;
  }

  bool get isTicking => _ticker.isTicking;

  void dispose() => _ticker.dispose();
}
```